# Can swap trace layout of differential pair through TVS/ESD component?

Tags: differential, esd, tvs

Im using 2 x TPD4EUSB30 to do TVS/ESD protection for the 4 differential pairs for a RJ45 ethernet jack.  To make some upstream routing a little easier I want to swap D1- and D1+.  Looking at the datasheet my gut feeling is that should be no problem but I'm posing the question here in case there's some nuanced reason to not swap them and connect them exactly as per the diagrams.

[image]

[image]

Also to be a little clearer I'm not looking to swap the + and - at the destination but just looking to route the traces a little differently through the TVS/ESD component so my overall routing can stay on the same layer and not cross over.

thanks!

Comment: Actually in a previous design I did swap the pair in question to seemingly no ill effect.  I'm leaving this question up for a bit to see what people have to say anyway.  thanks!

Comment: Will this part be between PHY chip and transformers, or between transformers and connector? Or is it a magjack?

Comment: i'm using a magjack

Answer (score 1):

Datasheet: [TPD4EUSB30](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpd2eusb30.pdf?ts=1680662527149)

[image: TPD4EUSB30 absolute maximum ratings]

Notice the ratings are absolute, not relative to each other.  That is, if there were some diodes between D+/-, they would have to be rated accordingly.  But they are rated independently (with respect to GND), so they are independent.  The characteristics also make no distinction between D+/-, so are identical structures.

It would also be difficult to use if it were sensitive, as Ethernet is bipolar (uses equal magnitude positive and negative voltages).

Mind, these are still only assumptions, and they could always be doing something really counter-intuitive.  I don't think that's the case here, but datasheets must always be read carefully and critically.

---

Note that further layout optimization options can be had by swapping around transformers (exchanging RX/TX), or their polarities, by the same reason.  That is, the magnetics are symmetrical between polarities, and between pairs* -- as long as you remember to make *all the same swaps* on both (PHY and media) sides, that is!  But, if you're having trouble keeping things straight, don't worry about it, just wire it per the datasheet and use vias if you have to.  Ethernet is very robust and doesn't at all mind a few vias.

*When they are.  Some are dissimilar, for reasons I don't know why.  There may be some reason to prefer RX/TX being on one set, in that case.

Even polarity isn't very picky; Ethernet almost always supports MDIX these days (polarity and some pair swaps (not necessarily all possible swappings) are resolved automatically).  Doesn't hurt to keep things consistent just in case, though.

Comment: Few points, Ethernet is bipolar and symmetric around 0V on the wire, not on the PHY side of transformer. And since four pairs must be protected, this is Gigabit Ethernet, and Auto-MDIX does not mean you can arbitrarily swap pairs or pair polarities, and a few improperly designed vias could affect the signal negatively.

Comment: According to https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3172/medium-dependent-interface-crossover-mdix "a gigabit Ethernet typically has 2 Auto-MDIX ports connected together". I'm not sure if that means the ports can also auto-swap, and a better reference would be nice.  If the transformer centertaps are simply bypassed (capacitor to GND, not biased to AVDD) this can be used on the PHY side; a higher voltage device is needed if biased.

Comment: You are misinterpreting what the web page says. Yes, Gigabit Ethernet ports are required to have Auto-MDIX. Yes, connecting two Gbit ports together with a cable means you are connecting two Auto-MDIX ports together. Yes, you can use either standard straight-thru cable or standard cross-over cable. No, it does not mean that any other combination of connecting the pairs will work, only those two.

Comment: Ok, then I am interpreting correctly what the web page says: it doesn't specify. So a better reference would be nice.